# Geometric inequality; angles in circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm currently trying to solve the question below.

### Abed is sitting in front of a large screen tv. He thinks he gets the best view when the screen takes up the maximum angle in his field of view.
What is the optimal point where he sits(to get the largest angle in his view)?

I think it has something to do with a geometric inequality, but I'm stuck at the first step, I can't find any way to progress. I've drawn a few constructions, but I still can't find the optimal point.

EDIT:

I forgot to clarify. We treat the TV as a line, and Abed is looking at it. He cannot leave the 'floor' so he can only move from left to right, not up and down.

Comment: What does your intuition suggest?  What happens if you start to the left of the line segment and move towards the left endpt of the line?  What happens if you start even with the left endpt of the line segment and move towards the middle of the line segment?  If your intuition *suggests* a **hypothesis**, you then have to use math to prove the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the screen to be the base of a triangle and the person sitting at the apex of the triangle at a distance of $a$ measured from the center of the base, what describes the locus of the apex for angle $\alpha \in (0^{\circ}, +180^{\circ})$ measured relative to the base? ***Hint:*** a semi-circle.

So, you describe the equation for the angle $\theta$ subtended by a symmetric line segment of the diameter, centered on the circle's center by point on a semi circle and maximize it.

[image: Visual of the problem statement]

As you vary the position of the viewing point on the circle, you get different angles of view. You also get different positions by varying the radius.

What radius of semi-circle maximizes the angle of view?

Theoretically, if the person places his eyes on the center of the screen, they get maximum angle of view $(180^{\circ})$. But, it is not practical. So, a radius is chosen depending on the person's viewing ability (at what distance is the individual able to focus).

Now, we just need to determine the maximum angle for a given $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the TV surface to be a flat rectangle, the normal to the screen at the center point of the rectangle maximizes planar and solid angles subtended by the viewing eye.

This is a consequence of symmetry of the field being viewed.

Answer after your EDIT:

Assuming the TV to be the red horizontal line the normal to the line at the center point of the line maximizes planar angle subtended by the viewing eye moving parallel to it on the ground as shown.

Let length of line TV be $2L$, point on considered on it from center at distance on ground $x$,central slant distance $a$ then total subtended angle

$$ \theta= \tan^{-1}\dfrac{L-x}{a}+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{L+x}{a} $$

Differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and simplify, resulting in the center point

$$ x=0 $$

[image]

Comment: sorry i need to clarify